If infinite $G$ is a finite union of cosets, prove some coset has finite index
I'm trying to solve this question from Wadsworth’s Problems in Abstract Algebra.
Let $G$ be an infinite group, and let $H_1, \dots, H_n$ be subgroups of $G$, not necessarily distinct. Suppose $G$ is a union of cosets, one for each $H_i$, say $G=a_1H_1 \cup \dots \cup a_nH_n$. Prove that there exists an $i$ such that $\mid G:H_i\mid < \infty$.
I see that we have made up an infinite group with a finite union. Thus, intuitively, each coset must cover at least $1/n$ of the group. However, I am not sure how to make my intuition into a formal proof.

This is a result of B. H.Neumann. See here for a link to the paper containing the proof.

Looks like a duplicate.
See for example here and here.
